# Resolved url function not equal to class based view `as_view()` method?

Tags: django, django-testing

I have the following test:

```
def test_root_url_resolves_to_home_page_view(self):
    found = resolve('/')
    self.assertEqual(
        found.func,
        views.HomePageView.as_view()
    )
```

gives this error:

```
AssertionError: <function HomePageView at 0x107d65620> != <function HomePageView at 0x107d97400>
```

Comment: This is an odd thing to test. `as_view` returns a new callable object each time, and without any other instructions objects are compared by id. What's the point of testing this?

Comment: It is a way of testing `urlpatterns` and that they use the correct `view`. It was used in a function based view example here: https://www.obeythetestinggoat.com/book/chapter_unit_test_first_view.html

Comment: @surfer190 if you read comments on the bottom of the page you've shared, you will see that this is already has been answered http://www.obeythetestinggoat.com/book/chapter_unit_test_first_view.html#comment-3279904435

Comment: The django docs had the answer and I have duly answered my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the [django 2 documentation on testing the response resolver](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.Response.resolver_match)

```
# class-based views need to be compared by name, as the functions
# generated by as_view() won't be equal
self.assertEqual(response.resolver_match.func.__name__, MyView.as_view().__name__)
```

In your case:

```
self.assertEqual(
        found.func.__name__,
        views.HomePageView.as_view().__name__
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Class based views; you can also do:

```
self.assertEqual(
    found.func.view_class,
    views.HomePageView
)
```